# C++ program compiled in windows produces different output

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc

I was solving a problem that involved incrementing a counter and displaying it. The way I initialized and incremented the variable seemed pretty normal. See **counter** variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[5];
    int counter = 1;

    while (cin >> s && (strcmp(s, "*") != 0))
    {
        cout << "Case " << counter++ << ": Hajj-e-A";

        if (s[0] == 'H')
        {
            cout << "kbar\n";
        }
        else if (s[0] == 'U')
        {
            cout << "sghar\n";
        } 
    }
}
```

but the program mysteriously displayed an incorrect result. It didn't increment the value, which started at 1, properly. See the output.

```
Case 1: Hajj-e-Akbar
Case 0: Hajj-e-Asghar
Case 1: Hajj-e-Akbar
Case 0: Hajj-e-Asghar
```

But when I tried compiling and running it through http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php, which uses Linux, it produced correct results. The program was also accepted by the online judge.

```
Case 1: Hajj-e-Akbar
Case 2: Hajj-e-Asghar
Case 3: Hajj-e-Akbar
Case 4: Hajj-e-Asghar
```

Anyone can point out the mystery behind this? Why is the Windows-compiled code producing weird results? Many thanks!

Comment: How long are the strings you're reading into the `s` array? Anything longer than 4 characters (plus the NUL terminator) will overflow the array and trash the following memory, possibly including your `counter` variable.

Answer (score 8):

This is a buffer overflow. Most likely, when you compile on Windows, the `counter` variable immediately follows the `s[5]` variable in memory, like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | 01 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
 \________ s[5] ________/ \____ counter ____/
```

Since Windows is little-endian, it's stored as `01 00 00 00` instead of  `00 00 00 01` like you might expect. The `??` just indicates that we don't know yet what's there - it could be anything.

Now, let's say you enter "Hardy" and press Enter. In ASCII, that translates to the byte sequence `48 61 72 64 79 0D 0A` (the last two are the line ending, on UNIX the `0D` would be omitted). This is what `cin >> s` will do to the memory:

```
1. Read in 'H':
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 48 | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | 01 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
2. Read in 'a':
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 48 | 61 | ?? | ?? | ?? | 01 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
3. Read in 'r':
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 48 | 61 | 72 | ?? | ?? | 01 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
4. Read in 'd':
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 48 | 61 | 72 | 64 | ?? | 01 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
5. Read in 'y':
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 48 | 61 | 72 | 64 | 79 | 01 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
6. Read in '\r\n' (or on UNIX, just '\n'), but this isn't put into the memory.
Instead, cin realizes that it has finished reading, and closes off the string with a '\0':
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 48 | 61 | 72 | 64 | 79 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
 \________ s[5] ________/ \____ counter ____/
```

Whoops! It overwrote the counter!

Why does it work correctly on Linux? Either Linux doesn't place the two variables adjacent in memory, or the Linux system is big-endian, which would mean the memory is instead laid out like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | 00 | 00 | 00 | 01 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

So even if you read in 5 characters, the final null terminator just replaces a 0 that was already there. Of course, if this is the cause, then reading in 6 characters would really mess things up.

And how do you fix it? The problem is that, to hold a string of length `n`, a character array needs to have a length of `n+1`. So you could do this:

```
char s[6];
```

Or even better, use a string:

```
std::string s;
```

(For that you need to `#include <string>`.)

Comment: Nice use of ASCII art. :-)